# Editor's toolbar is missing due to custom js file

Tags: javascript, wordpress, editor, text-editor, wp-editor

I've added a custom js file **`cr-scroll.js`** for a carousel on home page.
after adding it, page's editor's toolbar has been missed. If I remove that js file then everything works fine.

What is the issue to this js file? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

**I've added script with this code:**

```
wp_register_script('java1', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/cr-scroll.js?version=4.2', array( 'jquery' ));
wp_enqueue_script( 'java1' );
```

**My cs-scroll.js:**

```
var $k = jQuery.noConflict();
(function($k){
$k(document).ready(function($k) {
 $k.fn.make_carousel = function() {
    var speed = 0;
    var scroll = 0;
    var con = $k(this);
    var con_w = con.width();
    var max_scroll = con[0].scrollWidth - con.outerWidth();
    var prev_frame = new Date().getTime();
    con.on('mousemove', function(e) {
        var mouse_x = e.pageX - con.offset().left;
        var mouseperc = 100 * mouse_x / con_w;
        speed = mouseperc - 50;
    }).on ( 'mouseleave', function() {
        speed = 0;
    });

    function updatescroll() {
        var cur_frame = new Date().getTime();
        var time_elapsed = cur_frame - prev_frame;
        prev_frame = cur_frame;
        if (speed !== 0) {
            scroll += speed * time_elapsed / 50;
            if (scroll < 0) scroll = 0;
            if (scroll > max_scroll) scroll = max_scroll;
            con.scrollLeft(scroll);
        }
        window.requestAnimationFrame(updatescroll);
    }
    window.requestAnimationFrame(updatescroll);
}

$k("#carousel1").make_carousel();
$k("#carousel2").make_carousel();

function reset(){
    $k('.maincontent').find('*').removeAttr('class');
    document.getElementById('step1').setAttribute("class", "visible");
}
function back(){
    var previous_class = $k('.visible').data('previous');
    if(previous_class != ''){
        var current_class = $k('.visible').attr('id');
        document.getElementById(current_class).setAttribute("class","");
        document.getElementById(previous_class).setAttribute("class","visible");
    }
}
function show_next(current,next) {
    document.getElementById(current).setAttribute("class", "hidden");
    document.getElementById(next).setAttribute("class", "visible");
}

function show_hide(show_ele,hide_ele) {
    document.getElementById(show_ele).style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById(hide_ele).style.display = "none";
}
function load_after_sec(id) {
    count = 0;
    wordsArray = ["5", "4", "3", "2", "1"];
    var timerID = setInterval(function () {
        count++;
        if(count == 5){
            $k("#"+id).show();
            $k("#seconds_counter").hide();
            clearInterval(timerID);
        } else {
            $k("#num_sec").fadeOut(400, function () {
                $k(this).text(wordsArray[count % wordsArray.length]).fadeIn(400);
            });
        }                               
    }, 2000);
}
function showButton(){
    document.getElementById("btn_repeat").style.display='block';
}
});
})(jQuery);
```

This section comes in full width , but after including js, it comes in a inner class which has some defined width.

Comment: which hook you are using for add script? and can you post your cr-scroll.js code?

Comment: @George I've edited my question please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems you didnt use `wp_enqueue_scripts`. add this code in `functions.php` and try.

```
    function custom_scripts() {
        wp_register_script('java1', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/cr-scroll.js', array( 'jquery' ));
        wp_enqueue_script( 'java1' );
    }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_scripts' );
```

Comment: Thank you so much..Editor issue is solved but due to that js file, pricing page's design was changed in one section, and it is not solved yet.

Comment: `pricing page's` mean in frontend?

Comment: I cannot see the issue on front page https://halfpanthippo.com/. can you elaborate?

Comment: script error in your `cr-scroll.js` file. please check in console.

Comment: Thank you so much for figuring it out...it helped me a lot.

Comment: glad to help you :)